# Finding the Distance from A Pixel to an Edge

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, distance, edge-detection

I am trying to write an algorithm to find the minimum distance from every pixel in the image to an edge which is black. An example image is found below:

[image: edges of face]

This is the algorithm currently have:

> Starting from the pixel (R,C) I check every pixel around (R,C) that is d=1 pixels away
>   from R,C. If I do not hit a black pixel, then I check every pixel around (R,C) that is 
>   d =2 pixels away from R,C ... and this carries on (with d increasing) until I find a 
>   black pixel and then I calculate the Euclidean Distance from R,C. Note that I am making 
>   sure that the pixels I check do not exceed the boundaries of the image).

However because I am doing this for every pixel, the algorithm is very slow.

Does anyone know a faster way to doing this? Any help will be highly appreciated. I am coding in C++ and OpenCV so any algorithm making use of these will be preferred.

Comment: So, you want the distance for every X,Y in the image, to the nearest black pixel? And if you have an image like that one in the example, since there are FAR fewer black pixels than white, you should be able to have an index of black pixel locations [as long as the image is monochrome, you can store a "map" of where the edges of the black and white are for each row/column].

Comment: @MatsPetersson : +1 - I feel your comment should have been an answer.

Comment: have a look at distance transforms or chamfer distance / images. they can be computed in one pass quite efficiently and give you what you need. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to find a [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of the image. You can find the OpenCV implementation in the function [`distanceTransform`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042). You will find that it is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading for this job which would speed it up a bit.

Comment: Probably nowhere near as much as "being more clever in the algorithm" (e.g. using someone else's work - you can quite likely run that in parallel too).

Comment: But without any code I can not tell where he can use multithreading...  But I think Papouh's solution will be the best way.

Comment: My point was that you can improve 10x-1000x by changing the algorithm to something that doesn't do the simplest possible solution for the problem. Using multiple CPU's in multithreading will only give, at most the number of CPU's improvement - and often not even that, as you lose some of the efficiency in a multithreaded environment due to locking/data collisions, caches, etc.